# How to make a page which retrieves data from database based on click (php, JS)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I wanna make a static page that has infos inserted from the users and printed in the screen, all based on clicking.

Looking right now like this:

[image]

These buttons on the left I've already put on the database (I'm using Oracle 11g database):

CREATE TABLE x_teste (
id        NUMBER       NULL,
descricao VARCHAR2(10) NULL
);

the table i want to select to display on the right side of the screen:

CREATE TABLE x_teste_submenu (
id        INTEGER       NULL,
id_column INTEGER       NULL,
descricao VARCHAR2(255) NULL
)

---

PHP + Javascript Code below and what i tried:

index.php

```
<?php
        include_once("config/inc.php");
        $conn = new database;
        $bConectado = $conn->Conectar();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portal</title>
    <link href="bootstrap-5.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<?php include('header.php') ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-light">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <?php 
                    if ($bConectado){
                        $conn->Consultar("
                        SELECT ID, DESCRICAO FROM x_teste order by id ASC
                        ");
                        while (($ds = oci_fetch_array($conn->vResultadoSQL, OCI_BOTH + OCI_ASSOC))) {
                          echo
                            '<button class="btn lg-button btn-primary botao-painel mt-2" id="p'.$ds['ID'].'">'.$ds['DESCRICAO'].'</button>';                                                   
                      }
                    }
                    ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col p-5" id="a1">
             <?php 
                if ($bConectado) {
                    $conn->Consultar("
                    SELECT SB.DESCRICAO FROM X_TESTE_SUBMENU SB
                    INNER JOIN X_TESTE X ON X.ID = SB.ID_COLUMN
                    WHERE X.ID = 1"); // Manually inserted 1, but want to retrive the ID on the clicked button
                        while (($as = oci_fetch_array($conn->vResultadoSQL, OCI_BOTH + OCI_ASSOC))) {
                            echo '<p class="lead">';
                            echo 'An example 2-level sidebar with collasible menu items. The menu functions like an "accordion" where only a single ';
                            echo 'menu is be open at a time. While the sidebar itself is not toggle-able, it does responsively shrink in width on smaller screens.';
                            echo '</p>';
                            echo ''.$as['DESCRICAO'].'';                                                  
                        }
                }
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="bootstrap-5.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>              
    i = 1;
    $("#p"+i).click(function() {
    $("#a1").toggle(0);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need this: When I click on the button on the left panel, it retrieves the information from the database, table:" x_teste_submenu" and print on the div: , based on what button I've clicked.

With the while loop in PHP I have the id from each button, but cannot display the info on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic example is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button-clicked").click(function(){
    $("#div-you-want-to-update").load('location/code.php');
  });
});
```

In this example, whatever is generated by "code.php" will be loaded into the target div. In that file, you would make the database query and would write the code to iterate/display the results however you see fit.

You can either make a script for each button, or you can pass the specific button clicked as a variable to one PHP script that will interpret which button was clicked based on the variable. The latter will require using an AJAX call.